# Using spacing in MUI Grid2 gives padding problems

Tags: material-ui

Trying to use spacing in a grid that have full width. I'm assuming it should work like gap in css-grid however it gives me extra padding to the right and a horizontal scroll.

It also gives me padding bottom on the last row.
Not sure if gap is supported in Grid2 but that breaks even more.

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-gwen-yhb7ho?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1):

The `spacing` prop works in different ways.
Let me explain it a little bit:

If you add a spacing prop in the Grid component you will add padding on the bottom, right, and left in the first row or top row you can check it by opening the developer tool.

[image]

But add padding on every side on the other rows except the top row or first row.

[image]

So to add space horizontal or vertical you can use the following props to manipulate spacing.

1. rowGap
2. columnGap
3. rowSpacing
4. columnSpacing

> NOTE: Remember one thing before using gap props and spacing props: `gap, rowGap and columnGap` will add spaces between `divs, rows, columns, and others` on the other hand `spacing, rowSpacing, and columnSpacing` adds spaces on every side `top, right, bottom, and left.`

These props will allow you to add spcese in your prefered way.

To learn more about the Grid V2 (Grid2) [Head over to the Documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid2/#row-and-column-spacing)